# how do i override the static code block dynamically in a java class file

Tags: java, class, overriding

Original class is like:

```
    public class Test{

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("hello");
    }
    ...
    }
```

I want to change it to:

```
    public class Test{

    static {
        System.load("/home/abc/libhello.so");
    }
    ...
    }
```

The Test.class is in a jar file. I can't change the jar file. Any way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. If you need to change how code behaves, you need to change the code. Why can't you change the jar file?

Comment: I guess he has only .class files

Comment: @damluar: It depends on the situation. Maybe this is a signed/verified jar file. Maybe there's some other reason the OP can't change the jar file. What "bytecode level" were you talking about that *wouldn't* involve changing the jar file?

Comment: I thought by changing the jar, you meant decompile->change->compile again. Or you are proposing to change .class directly?

Comment: @damluar: Either way, it's going to be a problem if the OP's jar is signed and he can't re-sign it.

Comment: We need to follow the process and can't change any third-party jar, and decompile the code doesn't work for the libhello.so file. I am looking the some ways to modified the class file dynamically, like using cglib or others.

Comment: @Hebing: *Why* can't you change the third-party jar file? Is it a proprietary one? If so, ask the publisher. If it's an open source one, why can't you just rebuild it yourself? When you ask questions with unusual restrictions like this, it's really important that you explain the reasons for those restrictions.

Comment: it is company policy, the jar file is provided by another group, they won't do any customization for us.

Comment: @Hebing: That sounds like something you should take to management then. If they're producing something which simply won't work, you need your managers to talk to their managers. Anything else you might *try* to do is going to be much harder and cause much more long-term work than fixing the relationship between the two groups.

Answer (score 2):

No way to override.

You can always change the jar file. Use decompiler and get the source modify it and pack it back

Comment: it is company policy, the jar file is provided by another group, they won't do any customization for us

Answer (score 0):

`Test.class` is the compiled version of you `Test.java` file. If you want to change the behavior of your program, you have to change it in the `Test.java` file and recompile it.

Comment: it is company policy, the jar file is provided by another group, they won't do any customization for us